# How to upload a text file using google.colab import files and then converting it into a set of words?

Tags: python, dictionary, text, set

This a text file that I made for stop words in Spanish, and then I uploaded it to google collab:
srop_words_spanish.txt

This is my code:

```
from google.colab import files
spa = files.upload()
```

As you can see, the import was succesfull:

```
srop_words_spanish.txt(text/plain) - 3391 bytes, last modified: 11/22/2020 - 100% done
Saving srop_words_spanish.txt to srop_words_spanish (4).txt
```

However, it uploaded as a dict.

```
{'srop_words_spanish.txt': b'alg\xc3\xban\r\nalguna\r\nalgunas\r\nalguno\r\nalgunos\r\nambos\r\nampleamos\r\nante\r\nantes\r\naquel\r\naquellas\r\naquellos\r\naqui\r\narriba\r\natras\r\nbajo\r\nbastante\r\nbien\r\ncada\r\ncierta\r\nciertas\r\ncierto\r\nciertos\r\ncomo\r\ncon\r\nconseguimos\r\nconseguir\r\nconsigo\r\nconsigue\r\nconsiguen\r\nconsigues\r\ncual\r\ncuando\r\ndentro\r\ndesde\r\ndonde\r\ndos\r\nel\r\nellas\r\nellos\r\nempleais\r\nem.....
```

My goal is to convert the dict into a set of word without \r or \n or just open directly the text file like something like this:

```
stopspa=set(line.strip() for line in open("srop_words_spanish.txt", 
encoding='UTF-8'))
```

I want to know how to do both things.

Answer (score 0):

```
# clean up the dataset to remove unnecessary columns (eg. REG) 
df=df.drop(['Marca temporal','Nombre y Apellidos','Correo electrónico'], axis = 1)
df.columns = list(map(str, df.columns))
%load_ext google.colab.data_table
df
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

df['Comentarios'] = df['Comentarios'].replace('\n', '')
df['Comentarios'] = df['Comentarios'].replace('\r', '')

text=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
  text.append(df.iloc[i,0])text= 

" ".join([str(i) for i in text])
```